# Solr server URL needs to include a scheme?

Tags: 7, search

Recently I am facing a issue with all my D7 websites which I have migrated to a new server. The case is as follows

-> All Sites have been setup with Apache Solr and working fine on my old server

[image: old server config page]

> After I migrated the sites to new server I am getting this error

[image: new server config page]

URL Format Used :

> http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8983/solr/CORE_NAME

Note: I migrated to new server with latest version of LAMP. Also I use remote Solr server.

OLD Server : Ubuntu 12.04, PHP 5.3.10, Nginx 1.8.0, MySql 5.5.X

New Server : Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7.0.28, Nginx 1.10.3, MySql 5.7.X

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the '#' character in the password which was failing the parse_url called in the module.